# How to use stopDelay(agent) on AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, agent-based-modeling, anylogic, event-simulation

I am generating multiple agents at the source. I would like to let them wait until some event.

I am trying to access the "delay.stopDelay(agent)" however it requires an agent as a parameter.

How should I proceed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```java
Tasks t = null; 
if(delayTasks.size()>0){

    //use a random agent stored at delayTasks
    int i = uniform_discr(0, delayTasks.size()-1); 
    t=delayTasks.get(i); 

    //or use any specific condition
    for(int i=0; i< delayTasks.size(); i++){ 
    //if() any condition
        t=delayTasks.get(i); 
    } 

    //Then you release the agent t
    if(...){
        delayTasks.stopDelay(t);
    }
}
```